# trufflehog in gitlab ci

Tags: python, docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ce

I am attempting to manually setup truffleHog in GitLab CI to scan my GitLab repo for secrets. I think I've misconfigured my job. My guess would be the file path I'm passing to trufflehog is wrong, as the job runs quick and ends with a "job succeeded" despite the fact I have a dummy text file with "----BEGIN PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----" and "EAACEdEose0cBA23456gfde4567hgf" to test whether or not it's working as expected.

My `.gitlab-ci.yml` looks like:

```
stages:
  - secrets

trufflehog:
  stage: secrets
  image: python:3-alpine
  script:
    - apk add --no-cache git
    - pip install trufflehog
    - adduser -S truffleHog
    - trufflehog --entropy true "file://$PWD"
```

The raw output of the trufflehog command looks like this:

```
$ trufflehog --entropy true "file://$PWD" 
[0Ksection_end:1570219434:build_script 
[0Ksection_start:1570219434:after_script 
[0Ksection_end:1570219435:after_script 
[0Ksection_start:1570219435:archive_cache 
[0Ksection_end:1570219437:archive_cache 
[0Ksection_start:1570219437:upload_artifacts_on_success
[0Ksection_end:1570219438:upload_artifacts_on_success 
[0KJob succeeded
```

Any suggestions where I might be going wrong?

Comment: The raw output of the trufflehog command looks like this:  
  
[32;1m$ trufflehog --entropy true "file://$PWD"[0;m
section_end:1570219434:build_script
[0Ksection_start:1570219434:after_script
[0Ksection_end:1570219435:after_script
[0Ksection_start:1570219435:archive_cache
[0Ksection_end:1570219437:archive_cache
[0Ksection_start:1570219437:upload_artifacts_on_success
[0Ksection_end:1570219438:upload_artifacts_on_success
[0K[32;1mJob succeeded
[0;m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in [TruffleHog docs:](https://github.com/dxa4481/truffleHog)

For scanning a `repo` you should not use the "file" option:

```
truffleHog --regex --entropy=False https://github.com/dxa4481/truffleHog.git
```

Anyway, if you want to scan a local dir with file option, it seems there is not quotation marks on the call:

```
 truffleHog file:///user/dxa4481/codeprojects/truffleHog/
```

May you try it without the quotation if you have not spaces on dirs, or just this?

```
trufflehog --entropy true file:"//$PWD"
```

Comment: In the end I just couldn't get the file option to work, so I gave in and went the git route. Thanks!